# Getting Error Message (Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'password'.) while running Servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm making servlet to work with J2ME, but whenever running this one getting below error message.

Error:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'password'.)

```
public class GetNpostServlet extends HttpServlet
{
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
                     throws ServletException, IOException
{
// Same code appears in doPost()
// Shown both places to emphasize that data is received thru
// different means (environment variable vs stream), 
// yet processed the same inside the servlet
String acct = req.getParameter("account"),
        pwd = req.getParameter("password");    

String balance = accountLookup(acct, pwd);

if (balance == null)
{
  res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, 
 "Unable to locate  account.");            
  return;
}

res.setContentType("text/plain");    
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
out.print(balance);
out.close();
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
                    throws ServletException, IOException
{
// Same code appears in doGet()
// Shown both places to emphasize that data is received thru
// different means (stream vs environment variable), 
// yet processed the same inside the servlet
String acct = req.getParameter("account"),
        pwd = req.getParameter("password");    

String balance = accountLookup(acct, pwd);

if (balance == null)
{
  res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, 
"Unable to locate account.");            
  return;
}

res.setContentType("text/plain");    
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
out.print(balance);
out.close();
}

/*--------------------------------------------------
 * Lookup bank account balance in database
 *-------------------------------------------------*/
private String accountLookup(String acct, String pwd)
{
Connection con = null;
Statement st = null;
StringBuilder msgb = new StringBuilder("");

try
{
  // These will vary depending on your server/database      
  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:acctInfo");

  Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(
                     "Select balance from acctInfo where account = " +
                     acct + "and password = '" + pwd + "'");      

  if (rs.next())
    return rs.getString(1);
  else
    return null;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {                  
    return e.toString();
    }
    }

    }
```

Comment: I know that this not the cause of your problems, but your indentation is terrible.

Answer (score 5):

Most immediate problem: you're not quoting the `acct` string, and there's no space *after* it, so you'll end up with something like:

```
Select balance from acctInfo where account = fredand password = 'bloggs'
```

More *important* problem: you shouldn't be including values in your SQL like this in the first place. You should be using parameterized SQL. Currently your code is open to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Further security problem: Your code suggests that the passwords are being held in plain text. Please don't do this.

Design problems:

- You appear to be treating an account balance as a string. That's odd. `BigDecimal` would be a more natural representation.
- You're catching `Exception` rather than specific exceptions
- You're returning an exception string representation *as if it were an account balance*. Yikes! You should probably actually just let `SQLException` bubble up to the caller
- You're never closing the connection, statement or result set

Comment: Could you please tell me the exact issue where i am lacking in this code and i am fetching records from sql server using query-      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(
                     "Select balance from acctInfo where account = " +
                     acct + "and password = '" + pwd + "'");

Comment: @user1369219: I've shown you the exact issue pretty clearly - look at the sample SQL which will be generated... does that look right to you? I've also pointed out that you should be using parameterized SQL to avoid SQL injection attacks. If you do research on this you'll get to the right approach with prepared statements and parameters very quickly - but I'm afraid I don't have time to spoon-feed the code to you.

Comment: Thanks Dear Jon, i have tried and now i am able to work with same and i am going to connect with J2ME, please also help in this post--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495170/not-able-to-capture-image-via-mobile-nokia-c-series-and-send-command-is-not-work